# Foreach Insert into with same IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I want insert into data with same IDs.

**EXAMPLE:**

tbl_products

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| product_id | product_name | vendor_id | price |
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
|         P1 | A            |         1 |   500 |
|         P2 | B            |         1 |   500 |
|         P3 | C            |         1 |   500 |
|         P4 | D            |         2 |  1000 |
|         P5 | E            |         2 |  1000 |
|         P6 | F            |         2 |  1000 |
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

Example : `CUSTOMER 3` buy product A and B from `VENDOR 1` and buy product D and E from `VENDOR 2` I want to insert into with same `order_id` between two tables like this:

TBL: orders

```
+----------+------------+
| order_id | totalprice |
+----------+------------+
|       O1 |       1000 |
|       O2 |       2000 |
+----------+------------+
```

TBL: orders_detail

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| detail_id | get_order_id | get_product_id | get_vendor_id | get_customer_id |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|         1 |           O1 |             P1 |             1 |               3 |
|         2 |           O1 |             P2 |             1 |               3 |
|         3 |           O2 |             P4 |             2 |               3 |
|         4 |           O2 |             P5 |             2 |               3 |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

**MY CODE:**

```
$getcustomerid = $_SESSION['member_id']; // get customer id from member who's logged in
if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){

    mysql_query("insert into orders (orders_id, totalprice) values(NULL,'$totalprice' )") or die (mysql_error());

    $getorderid = mysql_insert_id();

    foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){
        $getproductid = $product["product_id"];
        $getvendorid = $product["member_id"]; // get vendor id from database
        mysql_query("insert into orders_detail (detail_id, get_orders_id, get_products_id, get_vendor_id, get_customer_id) values(null, '$getorderid', '$getproductid', '$getvendorid', '$getcustomerid')") or die (mysql_error());
    }
    header('location:check_out.php');
}
```

But my code has given results by insert one field into orders table and insert into `get_order_id` with the latest IDs like this:

TBL: orders

```
+----------+------------+
| order_id | totalprice |
+----------+------------+
|       O1 |       1000 |
+----------+------------+
```

And TBL: orders_detail

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| detail_id | get_order_id | get_product_id | get_vendor_id | get_customer_id |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|         1 |           O1 |             P1 |             1 |               3 |
|         2 |           O1 |             P2 |             1 |               3 |
|         3 |           O1 |             P4 |             2 |               3 |
|         4 |           O1 |             P5 |             2 |               3 |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: have you tried `lastInsertID`?

Comment: @SamTengWong i didn't use PDO method. :(

Comment: is it auto increment??? order_id

Comment: @devpro From orders table, Yes.

Comment: **Stop**  using depricated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead and learn about prepared statements.

Comment: if you want to add with same `id` the alter your order table for removing auto increment.

Comment: @Jens Sorry about  that, But on my server I can't using PDO. :(

Comment: @urfusion So how it's order_id run numbers?

Comment: if u also show the expected result than it will be good.. suggestion.

Comment: any success ? or still searching

Comment: @devpro Not success :( I don't know what to do now.

Comment: alright let me check,.. tell me it insert only one order and their details... right.

Comment: its 01 or O1 ???? its zero or O ??

Comment: @devpro Yes, Like my code results. it's O.

Comment: and in last u r expecting two orders?? O1 and O2 ???

Comment: @devpro Yes, When customer check out all products of VENDOR 1 should be insert into get_order_id with O1 and all products of VENDOR 2 : get_order_id = O2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103189/discussion-between-devpro-and-vintage-beef).

Comment: not responign, well , check print_r($_SESSION["products"]); before foreach loop and share result

Answer (score 0):

```
$getcustomerid = $_SESSION['member_id']; // get customer id from member who's logged in
if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){

mysql_query("insert into orders (orders_id, totalprice) values(NULL,'$totalprice' )") or die (mysql_error());

$getorderid = mysql_insert_id();

foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){
    $getproductid = $product["product_id"];
    $getvendorid = $product["member_id"]; // get vendor id from database
    mysql_query("insert into orders_detail (detail_id, get_orders_id, get_products_id, get_vendor_id, get_customer_id) values(null,'$getorderid', '$getproductid', '$getvendorid', '$getcustomerid')") or die (mysql_error());
}
header('location:check_out.php');
```

}

you have to put all values in ('') you forget to put $getorderid in ('') please check it

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried it and given same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments  `order_id` is auto incremented in table `order` that's why you are not able to use same id. Alter your table and remove auto increment from `order_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE orders CHANGE order_id order_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

You have to pass `order_id` each time you insert values.

Alternative way.

as you are saying

> CUSTOMER 3 buy product A and B from VENDOR 1 and buy product D and E
>   from VENDOR 2 I want to insert into with same order_id between two
>   tables

Then you should create a index `totalprice` and add the total of those products. then perform insert operation single time with `totalprice`.

Comment: How it's numbers running?

Comment: you can not use same `order_id` if `order_id` column is auto incremented. You have to pass `order_id` every time you insert value.

Comment: Then always order_id = 0 ?